# How to create Sample Openwhisk-Java application using maven and create Docker image for it

Tags: java, docker, openwhisk

I have created a sample maven project with `Hello World` O/P

Hello.Java:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println("Hello World");
}
```

DockerFile:-

```
FROM openwhisk/java8action
ADD target/app.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

I used

```
docker build -t myAppDocker
docker run myAppDocker
```

Its working fine.

Now I am replacing

```
public static void main
```

With

```
public static JsonObject main(JsonObject args)
```

But now I am getting below error

```
Error: Main method not found in class com.sample.maven.docker.CustomDocker, please define the main method as:
public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

What are the changes I need to do to work with it

Note: `void main` is Java's Main-Method , same way `JsonObject main` is openwhisk's Main-Method, I want to create it using OpenWhisk

Comment: You can have a “void main” and the openwhisk required main. This should make maven and OpenWhisk happy. The former could be and empty method.

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to create a docker image, but instead to prepare a jar and then deploy it with wsk create action. The actionlooop variant of the java runtime (openwhisk/actionloop-java-v8) also supports deploying a java source. Note that you are expected to get the paramtersa as a Json object and return the result as a Json object using the Google GSon library.